# Android Service takes ~5mins to start

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-service

I have a strange problem with my app. The App consists of one Service and one Activity, the service has to run "always" while the Activity is just an interface to control the service, and doesnt need to run a lot. 
So I want to create the service in my Activity's `onCreate()` if it doesn't run yet, and then bind to it. The code looks like this:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            mService= ((MyService.LocalBinder) binder).getService();
            mService.setView(ChatdroidActivity.this);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Controler = null;
        }
    }; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initUI();

        if(!MyService.isRunning()){
            Intent s= new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(s);


        }

        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  

        while(mService == null){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mService.doSomeStuff();
}
```

The problem is the Service doesn't seem to start. The app is in the while loop till i disconnect the debugger, after the Android message, that my app freezed.
And while I was searching the Web for a solution, suddenly my Eclipse came up, with an active breakpoint in my Service's `onCreate()`-method, for like 2 seconds, then it terminates. 
Logcat doesn't display any errors until I disconnect the debugger.
And the first line of my Services `onCreate()` is `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`
Before I added that call, the debugger never attached to the service.

Does anyone know this problem or better, a solution?

Answer (score 0):

- What happens if you move the mService.doSomeStuff() to the onServiceConnected() ? You don't need to do a while() loop to wait for it
- what does bindService return? It should return true in case nothing wrong happened
- put some logging in onServiceConnected() to see when it gets called
- what does your service do in the contructor? Is it hanging somewhere there?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the Answer. If i move mService.doSomeStuff() to onServiceConnected() nothing happens, since it doesnt get called.
bindService() returns true, and I put a Toast in the first line of onServiceConnected() nothing happens there.
My Service doesn't have a constructor, I use the onCreate()-Method as constructor. It has 3 calls, the first one is android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
the second one is a Toast, and the third one is putting a static public boolean, which indicates whether the Service runs or not, to true

Comment: And another question, why wouldn't I want to wait for the Service to be bound. Otherwise I get a NullPointerException when I try to call mService.doSomeStuff() after it. I can't leave it in the onServiceConnected, since it's just some data-feed to replace (later coming) userinput.

Comment: hmm, I don't know what is going wrong then. You have the interface implemented in the service that is supplied via the aidl? This is the object that is being return by the onBind() function in the service

Comment: http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android might help you

Comment: Did you declare an action in the intent filter of the service?

Comment: by the way: you don't need to do a 'startService' I think, as it will be started automatically when you do a bindService()

Comment: Ahm, I dont use an AIDL, my MyService.LocalBinder.getService() just returns the Serviceobject itself. I used this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#ownservice and I dont really think, that I have defined an Intent filter at all ...